# How do I stop WordPress from recommending to install the following Plugin

Tags: plugins

I installed a theme that gives you the option to install Elementor or Wp Bakery I chose Elementor.
It does not matter how many times I delete the following keeps showing up "This theme recommends the following plugin: WP Bakery Visual Composer. How can I disable this? Thank you.

Comment: You will need to ask the theme author. WordPress does not recommend themes or plugins this way. The recommendation, and the code that powers it, is coming from the theme. Therefore the method for removing it depends on the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to disable these before.  Once the theme is active, go to Appearance > Theme File Editor and go to the "functions" folder under "Theme Files" (the right-hand sidebar).  If there is a file with a name like "plugin-notify.php", open it and find the function which contains the message you are getting.  Then just alter the function name (e.g. add a "1" or something) and save it.

The theme will still try to run the notification function, but now there is no longer a function by that name.  I haven't experienced any fallout from doing this.